# preventDefault is not working on post request

Tags: php, jquery

I have some problem when I trying to delete data using form with post method, I did this because many people said using $_GET method is not safe enough. So I try using this method, 
I load the data from load.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

require_once('../../classes/Config.php');
require_once('../../classes/Database.php');
require_once('../../classes/Query.php');
require_once '../../classes/ErrorHandler.php';
require_once '../../classes/Validator.php';
require_once '../../classes/Token.php';

$connection = new Database($host, $username, $password, $database);
$main = new Query($connection);

$table = 'karyawan';
$selectData = $main->select($table);

while($fetchData = $selectData->fetch_object()){    
        $delete = '<form action="" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id_karyawan" value="'.$fetchData->id_karyawan.'"><input type="hidden" name="token" value="'.$_SESSION['token'].'"><a><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="delete" onclick="deleteData()">delete</button></a></form>';
        $button = '<td class="text-center">'.$delete.'</td>';   
    echo '<tr>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->id_karyawan.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->nama_karyawan.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->alamat_karyawan.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->telepon_karyawan.'</td>
            <td class="text-center">'.$fetchData->akses.'</td>
            '.$button.'
        </tr>';
}
```

in `$delete` I set a form with POST method, so I have some forms to delete these datas, here is where my load.php should be loaded,

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed bg-success">
        <thead>
            <th class="text-center">ID Karyawan</th>
            <th class="text-center">Nama Karyawan</th>
            <th class="text-center">Alamat Karyawan</th>
            <th class="text-center">Telepon Karyawan</th>
            <th class="text-center">Hak Akses</th>          
            <th class="text-center">Opsi</th>           
        </thead>
        <tbody id="load-data">

        </tbody>            
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"></td>
                <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="showTambah">Tambah</button></td>
            </tr>           
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="karyawan.js"></script>
```

and here is my jQuery scripts

```
load();
deleteData();

function load() {
    $('#load-data').load('process/karyawan/load.php');      
}

function deleteData(){  
    $('#delete').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('testing');
    });
}
```

when I click `delete` button function deleteData() didn't work well both of preventDefault() or alert() message.
Can someone give me some advices??

Comment: Do you want confirmation before delete?

Comment: No, in this case I just want to delete without confirmation.

Comment: do you want to submit form for delete or you want do ajax?

Comment: I think I want to submit form for delete data with ajax request

Comment: Just remove `onclick="deleteData()"` and put `$('#delete').click` outside the `deleteData()`

Comment: Do you mean like this ? $('#delete').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});

Comment: Yes whole `$('#delete').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert('test'); })` without any parent function

Comment: It doesn't work.. I guess the problem is because the datas I've loaded in load.php is looping so delete form also loaded with datas as well.. and automatically I have more than 1 id delete there..

Answer (score 0):

Remove `deleteData()` from submit button and add class called `btn-delete` on the button and remove `$('#delete').click(function(e){});` event and use `$('.btn-delete').on("click",function(e){});` this event. As your content loadind dynamically `click` event will not work you have to use below code.

```
$('.btn-delete').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("test")
});
```

Comment: It doesn't make any different.. the default action of submit form still run and preventDefault() function not working.

Comment: is form submitting?

Comment: yes the form is submitting / refresh the page because i don't put any action in form attribute